# How to check if a string ends with 'ed' in C++;

Tags: c++

How to write a program that reads 5 strings from user input and prints only those strings that end with the letter ‘ed’ in C++. Need help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Have you heard of the substring search?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is rather straightforward.

First we define a container that can contain 5 `std::string`. For that we use a `std::vector` together with a constructor to reserve space for the 5 elements.

Then we copy 5 strings from the console (from user input) into the vector.

And, last, we copy elements out of the `std::vector` to `std::cout`, if the strings end with "ed".

Because of the simplicity of the program, I cannot explain much more . . .

Please see.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

constexpr size_t NumberOfTexts = 5U;

int main()
{
    // Define a container that can hold 5 strings
    std::vector<std::string> text(NumberOfTexts);

    // Read 5 strings from user
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), NumberOfTexts, text.begin());

    // Print the strings with ending "ed" to display
    std::copy_if(text.begin(), text.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,"\n"), [](const std::string& s){
        return s.size()>=2 && s.substr(s.size()-2) == "ed";
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Elegant use of algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool endsWith(const std::string &mainStr, const std::string &toMatch)
{
    if(mainStr.size() >= toMatch.size() &&
            mainStr.compare(mainStr.size() - toMatch.size(), toMatch.size(), toMatch) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
int main()
{
   string s[5];
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      cin>>s[i];
   }
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      if(endsWith(s[i],"ed"))
         cout<<s[i]<<endl;
   }

}
```

Hope This might Helps:)